# Возможно ли создать взаимосвязанные ячейки в excel?

Tags: excel

Я хочу, чтобы при изменении любой из двух ячеек вторая тоже изменялась.

Например, если `A1 = 2 * A2`, то мне нужно, чтобы при изменении `A1`, `A2` автоматически бы выставилась в `A1 / 2`.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы, например, при вводе в ячейку `A1` числа 10 в ячейке `A2` получалось число 5, а при вводе в ячейку `A2` числа 10 в ячейке `A1` получалось 20?

Comment: В интернетах пишут, что такое можно сделать только с помощью VBA

Comment: @andreymal да, именно так. Как работает конвертер валют обычный, например.

Comment: @andreymal а можете ссылочку дать, где вы это нашли? Я не смог сформулировать так, чтобы что-то полезное гугл выдал.

Comment: Что-то типа такого: [раз](https://daveriskit.wordpress.com/2016/02/14/excel-bi-directional-temperature-converter/), [два](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/euppqf/), [три](https://superuser.com/questions/1407495) (код не читал, сам я VBA не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за помощь